# Android Studio won't launch app

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I switched from eclipse to android studio. I created a blank app for testing purpose and I was able to launch in properly. However, after having added some simple code I'm no longer to start. The error messages I get are:

```
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

or

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.

...

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/Tom/Java/Android/android_sdk_4.2/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/Tom/Java/Android/android_sdk_4.2/platforms/android-17/android.jar -M /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package app.beziehungen -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
    /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
    /Users/Tom/Programming/ToyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
....
```

So what is happening here. The code is defintely correct!

Comment: Have you downloaded Android SDK 5.0 in your SDK manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've downloaded the latest extras as well as the Android 5.0 SDK via the `SDK-Manager`.

And set your `compileSdkVersion` to 21 in your `build.gradle` file. You also probably want to change your `targetSdkVersion` to 21.

```
android {
    //...
    compileSdkVersion 21

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    //...
}
```